# error in mathematical expression

Tags: errors, equations

I type in the code shown below for a displayed formula. However the output is not what it should be. Can you tell me what is the mistake over here?

```
$$ \frac{(1-a)\frac{$q_{f}$}{{$q_{n}$}^a}}{$p_{n}$} \cdot $q_{f}$ \cdot $\Delta p$ $$
```

Comment: I removed the thanks (just the style here). Thanks is best expressed by upvoting helpful answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of All, You can't nest $ in $$. Therefore your formula should be like

```
$$ \frac{(1-a)\frac{q_{f}}{{q_{n}}^a}}{p_{n}} \cdot q_{f} \cdot \Delta p $$
```

Answer (score 8):

Building on Hassan Zakeri's answer, you have two potential problems. As Hassan says, you can't nest.

But it is also *much* better not to use `$$` to start display maths. Here's a better solution:

```
\[ \frac{(1-a)\frac{q_{f}}{{q_{n}}^a}}{p_{n}} \cdot q_{f} \cdot \Delta p \]
```

For further explanation, please read this question and its answers: [Why is [ … ] preferable to $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)